# In Django Signals, What is difference between these two codes?

Tags: django

First CODE:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Second CODE:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_or_save_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.profile.save()
```

Is there any difference in actually what they work?

Comment: The latter just combines the former into one method.  It really depends on what its being used for.  If the method is complicated with lots of logic, I would prefer to keep save and created separate.  The use case above, however, seems ok to combine with minimal readability issues

Comment: @Jason Thanks Jason, If you don't care, write it as answer, not comment, to choose your answer.

Comment: regarding the first code,  what if the second receiver will be called before the first one? Is there any guarantee of the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter just combines the former into one method. It really depends on what its being used for. If the method is complicated with lots of logic, I would prefer to keep save and created separate. The use case above, however, seems ok to combine with minimal readability issues